# Parsing Facebook api response (JSON) and retrieving the data

Tags: java, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm a Java Developer and couldn't find many resources to develop facebook apps on Java. 
Well I'm developing a Facebook app on Java which at some point, reads the inbox of a user. I was able to create a Login flow and get a long term access token. 
But as I'm very new to the JSON concepts, I could not able to parse the facebook response to get the required data.
I've read some tutorials and got to know basics of JSON and could able to write the code for parsing Simple JSON structures like:

```
{
"id": 1,
    "firstname": "Brad",
"languages": [
    { "lang":"en" , "knowledge":"proficient" }, 
    { "lang":"fr" , "knowledge":"advanced" }, 
]
"job":{
            "place":"Silicon Valley",
            "name":"Microsoft",
   }  }
```

But, I was unable to parse the Facebook response as it looks so complex, and I have referred various places for any example or sample code to Parse the Facebook's response for `/me/inbox` request and couldn't find any.
Here I'm looking for any sample code to parse the inbox JSON Object to get the required information for my App. 
Any effort is highly appreciated. 
Thank You.

**Edit:** I'm looking for a sample code in plain JSPs or Servelts.

Comment: Have you considered using JsonSlurper? Many tutorials available on the Nets.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Social is your friend.  Don't get bogged down in integrating with Spring Security (although there are a lot of examples) as the JavaScript login process will be sufficient to get an auth token for the user that you can then query Facebook's API with - just use Spring Social as a library to hide the complexity of the JSON and given you java objects to work with directly.

Comment: I'm looking for an example or a sample code in plain JSPs or Servelts... I'm Editing my question... Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to do it myself. The parent JSON element 'data' contained the data I was looking for. Then I used this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/) to format it and display it in a Facebook-like way.

I had to actually pick out the data I actually needed. Hope this helps!

You have to use `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`, which you can get from `getJSONObject()` and `getJSONArray()`. Once you've gotten the `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` you need, use `getJSONString()` to get the desired value.

The tutorial mentioned above is for Android, but the general idea is still there. Let me know if you have any questions. I've done a bit in `JSP` and `Java servlets` as well.